# Unable to delete ancestor tree using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to delete the rows of my html table inside a form whose checkboxes are checked.
Here is my HTML:

```
<table>
        <tr class="row">
            <td><input type="text"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  value="Delete" name="foo"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td><input type="text"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  value="Delete" name="foo"/></td>
        </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="btnDelete" value="Remove Selected"/>
```

Here is my jquery script:

```
$(function () {
        $('#btnDelete').on('click', function () {
            ;
            $('input[name=foo]').each(function (i, obj) {

                if (obj.checked) {
                    alert("clicked!!" + i + " " + jQuery.type(obj));
                    obj.parents().eq(1).empty();
                }
            });
        });

    });
```

Now on clicking the btnDelete, the script is invoked as alert shows up.But the grandFather element(i.e. `<tr>`) is not getting emptied with child getting deleted. Hence the pathogenic line seems to be:

```
obj.parents().eq(1).empty();
```

So how should I remove the table row(i.e.`<tr>`) along with its all child nodes whose checkbox is checked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try .has() function like

```
$('tr').has('input[name=foo]:checked').remove();
```

Your code will be reduced to

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnDelete').on('click', function () {
        $('tr').has('input[name=foo]:checked').remove();
    });

});
```

Comment: Change it to `.has('input[name=foo]:checked')` - to be sure - and you get my upvote. :)

Comment: Also works for me! and quite simple as well so I accept your answer with an upvote.Thanx!!!

Comment: +1. I like this more than my own answer. Though I would still suggest `.remove()` rather than `.empty()` (assuming there isn't a need to keep the empty tr around).

Comment: I would recommend as suggested by nnnnnn that .remove() must be used instead of empty() as it removes the tr.So I have edited your answer.

Comment: @rahulserver I initially answer it using `remove()` but later changed it to `empty()`. Your edit was rejected by the mods so I have edited my answer and changed `empty()` back to `remove()`

Answer (score 2):

Try `$(obj).closest('tr').empty();` (Thanks nnnnnn)

Why not keep it simple and try this: http://jsfiddle.net/H9WL7/

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnDelete').on('click', function () {
        $('input[name=foo]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $(this).closest('tr').empty();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The line that didn't work should've been `$(obj)...` instead of `obj...`

Answer (score 1):

The `obj` variable is a reference to the DOM element, it's not a jQuery object. Try this:

```
$(obj).parents().eq(1).empty();
```

...to get your existing code working. Or, better:

```
$(obj).closest('tr').remove();
```

Note that `.empty()` doesn't remove the tr element itself, it just removes all of its content, so I suggest `.remove()`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TWL2E/

Comment: But as you would admit that umairP's answer was better hence I am accepting his as the answer. Also since your answer also works, I upvote for you!!